# How to add desired policy to lambda with cloudformation & SAM

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cloudformation

I want to make a lambda function that has access to dynamoDB and other lambda functions.
However, I don't know how to make an appropriate YAML template for SAM to give appropriate permissions.

Especially, I don't understand the confusing 3 entries including definitions
of the permissions (AWS::IAM::Role, AWS::Serverless::Function, AWS::Lambda::Permission). Which entry should I use to add the necessary permissions?

Here is my YAML below. But the created my_lambda_role does not have AWSLambdaRole policy and policy for dynamoDB. As a result, the lambda fails to access to dynamoDB. Please tell me how to fix it.

```
  MyLambdaRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Service: lambda.amazonaws.com
          Action: sts:AssumeRole
      ManagedPolicyArns:
      - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole
      - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaRole
      RoleName: my_lambda_role

  OnConnectFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: onconnect/
      Handler: index.lambda_handler
      MemorySize: 256
      Role: !GetAtt MyLambdaRole.Arn
      Runtime: python3.6
      Environment:
        Variables:
          TABLE_NAME: !Ref TableName
      Policies:
      - DynamoDBCrudPolicy:
          TableName: !Ref TableName
      - Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Action:
          - 'execute-api:ManageConnections'
          Resource:
          - 'arn:aws:execute-api:*:*:*/@connections/*'

  OnConnectPermission:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
    DependsOn:
      - MyAPI
    Properties:
      Action: lambda:InvokeFunction
      FunctionName: !Ref OnConnectFunction
      Principal: apigateway.amazonaws.com
```

Answer (score 0):

You can **add the missing policies**. Depending on what you want, but if you want full access, then you can add `AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess`:

```
      ManagedPolicyArns:
      - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole
      - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaRole
      - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess
```

Comment: I got the following error. "Policy arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess does not exist or is not attachable. (Service: AmazonIdentityManagement; Status Code: 404; Error Code: NoSuchEntity"

Comment: @nemy Check in your IAM policies. Maybe the policy is called different for you, e.g. `AmazonDynamoDB_FullAccess`?

Comment: AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess exists. Which means this approach does not work.

Comment: @nemy The role is correct, as this is how you do it. Are you sure that your code in question factually represents your real code and situation?

Comment: Yes, the code is real. I also tried to add AWSLambda_FullAccess and also got the same error. It seems that *FullAccess is not allowed.